# UDP ping implementation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp, ping

I'm trying to implement ping based on udp packets with C#. The idea is to send udp packets to wrong port and get back ICMP packets contating Port unreachable error. And the time elapsed between seding the udp packet and recieveing the icmp packet is a ping time. I do it like that:

```
    // Start building the headers
    //Console.WriteLine("Building the packet header...");
    int messageSize = 64;
    byte[] builtPacket, payLoad = new byte[messageSize];
    UdpHeader udpPacket = new UdpHeader();
    ArrayList headerList = new ArrayList();
    Socket rawSocket = null;
    SocketOptionLevel socketLevel;

    // Initialize the payload
    //Console.WriteLine("Initialize the payload...");
    for (int i = 0; i < payLoad.Length; i++)
        payLoad[i] = (byte)'0';

    // Fill out the UDP header first
    //Console.WriteLine("Filling out the UDP header...");
    udpPacket.SourcePort = 33434;
    udpPacket.DestinationPort = 33434;
    udpPacket.Length = (ushort)(UdpHeader.UdpHeaderLength + messageSize);
    udpPacket.Checksum = 0;

    Ipv4Header ipv4Packet = new Ipv4Header();

    // Build the IPv4 header
    //Console.WriteLine("Building the IPv4 header...");
    ipv4Packet.Version = 4;
    ipv4Packet.Protocol = (byte)ProtocolType.Udp;
    ipv4Packet.Ttl = 30;
    ipv4Packet.Offset = 0;
    ipv4Packet.Length = (byte)Ipv4Header.Ipv4HeaderLength;
    ipv4Packet.TotalLength = (ushort)Convert.ToUInt16(Ipv4Header.Ipv4HeaderLength + UdpHeader.UdpHeaderLength + messageSize);
    ipv4Packet.SourceAddress = sourceAddress;
    ipv4Packet.DestinationAddress = destAddress;

    // Set the IPv4 header in the UDP header since it is required to calculate the
    //    pseudo header checksum
    //Console.WriteLine("Setting the IPv4 header for pseudo header checksum...");
    udpPacket.ipv4PacketHeader = ipv4Packet;

    // Add IPv4 header to list of headers -- headers should be added in th order
    //    they appear in the packet (i.e. IP first then UDP)
    //Console.WriteLine("Adding the IPv4 header to the list of header, encapsulating packet...");
    headerList.Add(ipv4Packet);
    socketLevel = SocketOptionLevel.IP;

    // Add the UDP header to list of headers after the IP header has been added
    //Console.WriteLine("Adding the UDP header to the list of header, after IP header...");
    headerList.Add(udpPacket);

    // Convert the header classes into the binary on-the-wire representation
    //Console.WriteLine("Converting the header classes into the binary...");
    builtPacket = udpPacket.BuildPacket(headerList, payLoad);

    // Create the raw socket for this packet
    //Console.WriteLine("Creating the raw socket using Socket()...");
    rawSocket = new Socket(sourceAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);

    // Bind the socket to the interface specified
    //Console.WriteLine("Binding the socket to the specified interface using Bind()...");
    IPAddress bindAddress = IPAddress.Any;
    rawSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(bindAddress, 0));

    // Set the HeaderIncluded option since we include the IP header
    //Console.WriteLine("Setting the HeaderIncluded option for IP header...");
    rawSocket.SetSocketOption(socketLevel, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1);
    rawSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);

    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            timer.Reset();

            timer.Start();

            int rc = rawSocket.SendTo(builtPacket, new IPEndPoint(destAddress, 0));
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to {1}", rc, destAddress);

            Socket icmpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
            icmpListener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(sourceAddress, 0));
            icmpListener.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 });
            icmpListener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            try {
                int bytesRead = icmpListener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remoteEndPoint);
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved " + bytesRead + " bytes from " + destAddress + " in " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms\n");
            }
            catch {
                Console.WriteLine("Server is not responding!");
            }
            finally {
                icmpListener.Close();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (SocketException err) {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket error occurred: {0}", err.Message);
    }
    finally {
        rawSocket.Close();
    }
```

And it works from time to time. The thing is that some web-sites send me an icmp packet and some not. Actually at first they also were not sending then I used Windows ping to ping them and tracert to traceroute them. And changed port number and it worked. But not for all. I can ping only google.com and one more site but others don't send icmp packet back. The same situation with local network computers I tried to ping. I send udp packet and don't get icmp back.

I used wireshark to watch packets flying.

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: I don't see a question in there. Some servers probably have the ICMP suppressed by their firewall to avoid discovery.

Comment: Well at first google.com also didn't response, but later started. And what about computers in local net? Maybe I did something wrong in initializing sockets or something else?

Comment: http://www.rikfarrow.com/Network/net0700.html

Comment: what exactly should I read in there and understand? what did you mean?

Comment: Well... the fact that most firewalls block ICMP response to ping requests?